# multselect box only updates output in mysql table by the first selected field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that supposed to add data to two mysql tables recipes and recipe_ingredients. The latter which is a link entity. One of the fields in the form a multiselect drop down box. When i use CTRL to select multiple entrys the results only return one chosen options in the drop down box...i have been at this for hours..any sugguestions..here is my code

HTML FORM

```
<table class="form_table">
<tr><form method="POST" onSubmit action="thankyou.php">
</tr><tr>
<td class="ctable_row">Recipe Name:</td>
<td class="ctable_row"><input type="text" name="recipename"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="ctable_row">Recipe Author:</td>
<td class="ctable_row"><input type="text" name="recipeauthor"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ctable_row">Cook Time (hh:mm:ss): </td>
<td class="ctable_row"><input type="text" name="cooktime"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ctable_row">Select From A List of Ingredients<br/>(**hold CTRL to ``select<br/> multiple values**)</td>
<td class="ctable_row"><select multiple="multiple" name="Ingredients[]">
    <option value="Broccoli">Broccoli</option>
    <option value="Carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="Macaroni">Macaroni</option>
    <option value="Oil">Oil</option>
    <option value="Flour">Flour</option>
    <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
    <option value="Eggs">Chicken</option>
</select>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="ctable_row">Recipe Stages</td>
<td colspan="2"><textarea rows="20" cols="65" name="stages">
 Input Recipe Stages here...
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td></tr>
</form>
 </div>
</td>
```

PHP CODE

```
session_start(); $q=mysql_connect("localhost",'root','');

$db=mysql_select_db("tasteofhome");



$recipename=$_POST['recipename'];

$recipeauthor=$_POST['recipeauthor'];

$cooktime=$_POST['cooktime'];


$stages=$_POST['stages'];


$name=$_SESSION['login_user'];


$sql2="SELECT user_id from users where user_name='$name'";
$q1=mysql_query($sql2);


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){



$s="insert into recipes (recipe_name,recipe_author,cook_time,stages_description,user_id)values('$recipename','$recipeauthor','$cooktime','$stages','$row[0]');
";


$sql5=mysql_query($s);

}
if($sql5 === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
if($sql5)
{


}

else {
echo "data not inserted";

}

foreach ($_POST['Ingredients'] as $selectedOption){


$sql="select ingredients_id from ingredients where ingredients_name='$selectedOption' ";

$q=mysql_query($sql); }

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array ($q))

{

$sql3="select recipe_id from recipes where recipe_name='$recipename' ";

$s=mysql_query($sql3);



echo $rows[0]   ;

while ($table2=mysql_fetch_array($s))

{



$sql2="insert into recipe_ingredients (ingredients_id,recipe_id)values('$rows[0]','$table2[0]')";
$w=mysql_query($sql2);
}}
if($w)
{
echo "Data succesfully entered in the database
";

}


if($w == true){
header ('refresh:2;url=myrecipes.php');

}

?>

Back
```

Comment: what returns this query for each option? `$sql="select ingredients_id from ingredients where ingredients_name='$selectedOption' ";` did u checked $_POST['Ingredients'], is this array?

Comment: that query is a basically a value from a session..its the name of the user who logs on and is used by php to assign the recipe being created to the user who creates it...im new to php so im having some trouble

Comment: but what is the result of this query? maybe you dont have data in database and this query return 0 rows for some igredients?